# PHP: хранить данные в Cookie или в базе данных?

Tags: php, mysql

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как организовать хранение настроек пользователей: в cookie или в базе данных?
Например, пользователь на сайте выбрал, что он из города Самары, соответственно - ему показывается информация(объявления) для этого города. Также он выбрал себе в избранное определенные позиции товаров. В результате мы имеем id города и id понравившихся товаров.

Вопрос в чем: эти данные можно установить пользователю в Cookie и при его посещении сайта получать эти идентификаторы! Но, этих данных может быть очень много!

Это навело мне на мысль, что можно устанавливать пользователю в Cookie идентификатор, а все его настройки хранить в базе данных.

Таким образом, он заходит на сайт, мы получаем идентификатор Cookie, которые установили до этого. По идентификатору ищем в базе строку, где хранится вся инфа и дальше с ней работаем. После этого обновляем в базе дату Cookie и снова устанавливаем их пользователю.

Но насколько это оправданно? Если каждый запрос к странице будет сначала доставать данные пользователя, затем обновлять дату, чтобы определить активность пользователя. Не станет ли базе тяжко выполнять при значительной посещаемости?

Вижу, что на популярных сайтах вроде авито и т.д. есть id пользователей и никакая конкретная информация типа geo_id и т.д. не устанавливается. Как это работает, кто имеет опыт или какие мысли?

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: В куках - это у него. В базе - это у тебя. Вот от этого и пляши. Но учти, что надёжность хранения куков - нулевая. Уж лучше минимальная авторизация (ну а браузер пусть уже логин-пароль запоминает - как я понимаю, ничего важного в профиле храниться не будет).

Comment: Для начала ответьте на вопрос - пользователь, зашедший на сайт с другого устройства/браузера это тот же пользователь или другой?

Comment: @Akina, Тут дело не в том, авторизован пользователь или нет. Это может быть случайный посетитель. Например вы зашли на сайт, выбрали какие-то товары и ушли. Через какое-то время зашли на сайт снова и у вы видите все товары, которые вы выбрали раньше. Таким образом, мы поличим ваш id состоящий из n-го количества символов и по этому значению найдем все ваши данные.

Comment: @AntonShchyrov, Если это не зарегистрированный пользователь, то конечно идентификатор будет другой. А если зарегистрирован, то мы по нему выполним поиск и получим искомые данные.

Comment: *Это может быть случайный посетитель.* Ну коли так - реализуйте и то,  это. И отдайте приоритет своему, наверное...

Comment: @Akina, знаю, что вы знаток БД. Насколько это нагрузит базу данных, если каждая страница сначала выберет из базы идентификатор, а затем запишет туда новую дату(чтобы знать, когда заканчиваются cookie для их удаления по окончанию. В случае, если пользователь зашел или не вернулся, либо очистил cookie)

Comment: В смысле страница дёрнет куку, и потом полученный ID будет проверяться на существование в БД и, если нет, вставляться? Ерунда, один запрос, к тому же с выборкой одной записи по индексу.

Comment: @Akina Да, это будет "insert into on duplicate update". Т.е. если есть, то обновить, если нет, то добавить.

Comment: Гм... что Вы собрались там обновлять-то? на момент этой проверки, как я  понимаю, обновлять нечего, юзер ещё даже чихнуть на вашу страницу не успел...

Comment: @Manitikyl, Каждый раз пользователю не будет дан новый id. Он устанавливается один раз! Если его нет, то он устанавливается, а если он есть, то обновляется только дата исключительно для актуализации, т.е., чтобы в дальнейшим скриптом удалить все старые, неактивные идентификаторы, к примеру старше 30 дней.

Comment: @Akina Обновлять дату посещения. Кука устанавливается на 30 дней. В таблице мы имеем такую структуру: идентификатор, данные и дату. Чтобы таблица не "пухла", на нужно знать, чтобы удалить, наверняка, есть идентификаторы, которые уже не активны, то есть те, которые больше 30 дней. Чтобы знать эту информацию, нужно обновлять дату при посещении пользователей.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ваш вариант с идентификатором в Cookies очень похож на существующую систему сессий в PHP. Все что записано в массив $_SESSION будет храниться на сервере в специальных файлах, а пользователь получит куку-идентификатор (phpsessid) по которой при каждом запросе данные в $_SESSION будут восстановлены.

Минус такого метода, что по умолчанию время жизни сессии - до закрытия браузера. Это можно настроить, но это не лучшее решение.

Поэтому обычно используют свою собственную куку для идентификации пользователя.

И да, данные положено хранить именно в базе данных а никак не в куках. В куках только идентификатор для их получения.

Во-первых потому что куки доступны для модификации пользователем, а это потенциальная брешь в безопасности.

Во-вторых если данных довольно много, то это увеличение объема трафика и времени открытия страницы, так как куки передаются браузером каждый раз при каждом запросе на сервер.

Ну и в третьих это просто неудобно, с куками тяжело работать, не предназначены они для хранения объемных данных.